# Introduction to jBPM

Tags: jboss, jbpm

Part of the existing system at work uses jBPM, and a new module I need to put together needs it. However, I have no idea where to start on learning how to work with it.

I have access to JBoss 4 on the server, and whatever I'd need to do local development. I have no experience with anything JBoss, whether it be the server, jBPM, etc.

The only thing similar to a tutorial I can find is the user manual, which seems to assume that you have a working knowledge of a lot more than I do to be able to put it to use. I've also never used Ant (aside from running some pre-made build scripts from within an IDE) or JHibernate, which both seem to be important for me to understand it.

I'm being given about a week to learn everything I can about it.

What would be a good starting point, either a book or a website, for me to learn how to use JBoss and co.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read **jBPM Developer Guide by Mauricio Salatino** . Well written book for JBPM 3.2.
For JBPM 4.4, you can read **Spring Enterprise Recipe**, just one chapter for JBPM 4.4 there.

Answer (score 2):

You could go to a jBPM training by Red Hat, that will teach you more or less everything in 3(?) days.

Otherwise the [project home page](http://www.jboss.org/jbpm) has a very comprehensive [User Guide](http://docs.jboss.com/jbpm/v4/userguide/html_single/) that should get you started (you may already know this, as I understand from your question). Browse around the jBPM home page, wiki and forums to get a feel for it.

Of course the jBPM guide will not explian how to use ant of Hibernate. But then you don't need Hibernate (knowledge) to get started with jBPM.

Comment: Do you have any experience with jBPM training by Red Hat?

Comment: I did take such a training around 7 years ago and found it very good at that time. Of course this is does not tell anything about todays trainings.

Comment: Did training covered more advanced topic or basic ones? I am interested in best practices, how to's from real projects, experiences etc. Basics topics can be read in documentation.

Comment: I don't recall - and even if I did, I doubt it would be still applicable 7 years later.

Answer (score 2):

Well you can go through userguide available on Jboss

http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v5.4/userguide/

Also you can refer to various blogs written by various authors 
like

http://blog.athico.com/2011/01/recent-jbpm-5-blogs-articles-videos-and.html

http://kverlaen.blogspot.in/

https://community.jboss.org/people/bpmn2user/blog/2011/12/18/jbpm5-web-example--local-human-task

i hope that this links are helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

May be the following links help you to start with

http://www.jorambarrez.be/blog/        [This is specially very good, from one of the best jbpm authors]

http://www.mastertheboss.com/jbpm/186-jbpm-web-application.html

For advanced spring integration related article:

http://n.tomek.bujok.info/index.php/Spring_integration_in_jBPM_4

http://www.theserverside.com/news/1363804/Getting-Started-with-jBPM-and-Spring